# A Question about my cat (grammar)

Tags: grammar

I wanted to tell someone that it's been a while since our cat travelled with us and that's why she's scared. What is the correct way of saying that?

Our cat didn't drive with us in a while? Or should I use hasn't?

Comment: Maybe "it's been a while since our cat travelled with us and that's why she's scared"

Answer (score 2):

I would use **hasn't**. Alternatively, you could also use the same sentence that you used to explain what you're trying to tell them:

> It's been a while since our cat traveled with us, which is why she's scared.

Or, as you were asking:

> Our cat **hasn't** traveled/driven with us in a while.